# Git: Find last SHA merged into a branch

Tags: git, merge

I have my master branch and a dev branch that I periodically merge to master:

```
dev      --A---B---C---D---E---F---G--
        /       \       \
master ----------M1------M2----------
```

M1 and M2 are merge commits.

How can I find the SHA of the last commit on dev that has been merged into master? In this example, I want the SHA of commit D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the most recent common ancestor, or merge base :

```
git merge-base master dev
```

Answer (score 2):

If you never merge *to* the dev branch you're golden with the `git merge-base`. If you're merging from master as well, you have to check master's first-parent history for the most recent merge commit whose second parent is in dev's first-parent history.

Brute force:

```
awk '   ARGIND==1 { tomaster[$NF]=1; next }
        $1 in tomaster { print; exit }
' <(git rev-list --first-parent --merges --parents master) \
  <(git rev-list --first-parent dev)
```